# Is it possible to output something not in an element in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure if this is a stupid question (I sense downvotes) but I searched online and haven't been able to find any useful information.

If I want display something on the page I can use:

```
document.getElementById("id").value="whatever";
```

Is it possible to get rid of the notion of having elements here so that I can do something like:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>write something here with javascript, no need for element?</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know this can be achieved by using something like:

```
function e(){
    return "whatever";
}
```

But I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs) QRCode generator which *requires* an ID. However I'm dynamically generating a few rows of QR codes in a `c:forEach` loop with `JSP` and I can't figure out how to display a QR code for each iteration of the loop.

JSP context:

```
<c:forEach items="item" var="${items">

    <!-- display QR code here with value from ${item.qr} -->

</c:forEach>
```

This is what happens when I use something like:

```
<c:forEach items="item" var="${items}">

    <script>
        new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), "${item.qr}");
    </script>

    <div id="qrcode"></div>

</c:forEach>
```

Result:

[image]

Fixed by doing:

```
<c:forEach items="item" var="${items">

    <script>
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.id = "${item.id}";
        new QRCode(document.getElementById("${item.id}"), "${item.qr}");
    </script>

</c:forEach>
```

Comment: [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/document/write)? You could also create elements.

Comment: @yuriy636 Can `document.write()` be used instead of specifying an element where an element may be required in a function?

Comment: How is a script tag not an element? In any case, I don't understand the problem. You're iterating, into rows, what's the issue with having an id? Where else would you put the output?

Comment: You mean something like this?   `<script> 
     document.write("whatever")
  </script>` http://jsbin.com/miceyarube/edit?html,console,output @px06

Comment: Or are you asking how to use Java values as parameters to JavaScript functions in the loop?

Comment: Well I don't really care about  Java in this issue because the JSP has a for the QR code I'm trying to generate. All I need to do is generate them for every single row respectively and I can't see how to do it with a `div`, check my update.

Comment: You're using the same id for each div.

Comment: Yeah, so I think more specifically I'm more interested in how I can achieve it without using divs at all, I'm not very educated in JavaScript; so is there a way to use something like a current position instead of element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an element and it's text like this:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = "yourID";
var divText = document.createTextNode("Whatever");
div.appendChild(divText);
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

So in terms of your html code, it would be

```html
<html>
        <body>
            <script>
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.id = "yourID";
                var divText = document.createTextNode("Whatever");
                div.appendChild(divText);
                document.body.appendChild(div);
                div.addEventListener("click", function(el) {
                    alert("clicked the created element with id: " + el.target.id);
                }, false);
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I think this may be the best way of doing it, but how can I identify the created div with `createElement` with ID's? Can I assign ID's to those created divs?

Comment: Fixed my problem using your suggestion of creating the element like, there was no need to append it to the body though, but it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Well you are inside an element : body

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
body[0].innerHTML += "<script> your code </script>";
```